# How to delete delete app inventor watermark

Tags: android, watermark

I created some demo apps with M.I.T android app inventor and I was very happy with them.  This was until I notices when I pressed the button on the left hand side of my device (I believe it is the settings button) I got a screen with 2 buttons, one that would close the Application and the other that would pull up a dialog telling the user the App was made with M.I.T app inventor.  I want to make my first games in App inventor until I am more familiar with the android sdk, but I am not going to do so if their is a bad low-res watermark hidden in the application.  Is their a way to edit the files to not display this watermark?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it in a three steps:

1. Learn Java
2. Learn Android SDK
3. Create your app in Java with Android SDK and Android Studio

After that, you won't see App Inventor watermark.